# Unable to understand struct to char* conversion

Tags: c++, struct, char

I have defined a struct data and assigning it to a char*. However the size of strlen function always gives result as 1 and cout doesn't show anything. Here is my code:

```
    struct data
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    int main()
    {
        data d;
        d.x = 10;
        d.y = 20;
        char *ch = (char*)&d;
        cout <<"Length:" strlen(ch) << endl;
        cout << ch << endl;

    }
```

The output is:
Length: **1**

Please help me in understanding what's going on ?

Comment: Don't treat the type system so badly. What has it done to you?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Are you trying to get a string from the structure somehow? Please explain what the goal is, and we can better help you reach that goal. I recommend you read about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strlen` function counts all bytes in the passed string until it finds the character `'\0'`. This character is the same as the integer `0`.

So what the call to `strlen` is count the number of bytes until it finds a zero, and in your case the zero happens to be in the second byte of the structures binary representation, meaning that the "string length" is one.

The only thing that you can deduce from this is that you are on a [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system. Other than that, the call is *undefined behavior* as the "string" isn't actually a string.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it returns 1 is because you are treating the struct as a char array. Doing this you are re-interpreting the contents of the struct - the integer `10`, which is probably stored in memory as `0x0A000000` - as a string. And that yields a length of 1 (only 1 non-zero value before a null-character in the array)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're trying to treat something as a string which isn't a string, if all you want to do is print out the values in the struct, you can do something like:

```
struct data
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
int main()
{
    data d;
    d.x = 10;
    d.y = 20;
    cout << "x is " << d.x << ", y is " << d.y << endl;

}
```

Why **are** you trying to treat that struct as a string?